# UIBarButtonItem Custom Image is Stretched (Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, icons, uibarbuttonitem

I'm creating a side menu in Xcode, and to open it I'm using a navigation view controller like the following:

[image: Screenshot]

I need the left bar button item to be on the left.

I added a left bar button item. Without changing it to a custom image, it is aligned to the left, as desired. When I change it to the custom image (the three lines) it stretches and aligns itself in the center. I have not written any code for this view controller yet, so none exists for the bar button item.

How can I get this aligned to the left as it should be? (Above the "Home" text).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your menu icon size is bigger.I have added two images one is with 64*64 px size which is perfect and in another icon with 512*512 px size [image: 512 px size menu icon]

[image: 64 px size menu icon]

Hope it will help.Thank you.

Comment: I’m using a PDF vector on a universal scale though. Why can’t that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use any image size for UIKit tab bar or navigation items. 
Please read this guideline from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/